# Api occasionally slows down at runtime, possibly due SQL/connections

Tags: c#, performance, sql

I'm currently working on an API that behaves incredibly unpredictable at runtime. Context: We run the same call 100 times without delay in between. A call can take anywhere from ~200 ms to ~**5 seconds**. Usually it 'builds up' gradually and drops down quickly after about half a minute. This problem only occurs on a select few environments/databases. Not reproducable on local dev machines.

Initially the ceiling was about 10 seconds. After some refactoring already, making everything work smoothly in async, we have managed to reduce those long API calls to ~ 5 seconds. Relevant code is pasted below, all 1 class.

For the record, the code works. I've occasionally left out some code and replaces with ... because not relevant.

```
public async Task<Schedule> Get(Guid id) {
  var templateInfoRecords = TemplateInfoRecords(id);
  var scheduleDayInfoRecords = ScheduleDayInfos(id);

  var resultTemplateInfos = new List<ScheduleTemplateInfo>();

  foreach (var record in await templateInfoRecords.ConfigureAwait(false)) {
    int scheduleTemplateId = record.TMPLDAY_ID;
    int scheduleTemplateStartoffset = record.TMPLDAY_STARTOFFSET;
    int scheduleTemplateCyclenumber = record.TMPLDAY_CYCLENUMBER;
    int scheduleTemplateNumber = record.TMPLDAY_DAYNUMBER;
    var dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)(scheduleTemplateNumber - 1);
    DateTime? tmpldayEnddate = record.TMPLDAY_ENDDATE;
    DateTime tmpldayStartdate = record.TMPLDAY_STARTDATE;
    DateTime tmpldayCreation = record.TMPLDAY_CREATION;

    var sessions = FillUpSessionsAsync(record, scheduleTemplateId);

    resultTemplateInfos.Add(new ScheduleTemplateInfo(
      record.Id,
      tmpldayCreation,
      new PeriodOfApplicability(new ScheduleTemplatePeriod(tmpldayStartdate, tmpldayEnddate), dayOfWeek,
        scheduleTemplateCyclenumber.ToScheduleTemplateRecurrencePattern(scheduleTemplateStartoffset)),
      await sessions.ConfigureAwait(false)));
  }

  return new Schedule(resultTemplateInfos, await scheduleDayInfoRecords.ConfigureAwait(false));
}



private async Task<ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo[]> FillUpSessionsAsync(dynamic record, int scheduleTemplateId) {
  var sessionsTasks = new List<Task<ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo>>(3);

  if (record.TMPLDAY_START1 > -1) {
    sessionsTasks.Add(GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo1(record, scheduleTemplateId));
  }
  if (record.TMPLDAY_START2 > -1) {
    sessionsTasks.Add(GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo2(record, scheduleTemplateId));
  }
  if (record.TMPLDAY_START3 > -1) {
    sessionsTasks.Add(GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo3(record, scheduleTemplateId));
  }

  await Task.WhenAll(sessionsTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);

  return sessionsTasks.Select(sessionsTask => sessionsTask.Result).ToArray();
}



private async Task<ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo> GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo1(dynamic record, int scheduleTemplateId) {
  var session1ProgramRecords = GetPrograms(scheduleTemplateId, record.TMPLDAY_START1, record.TMPLDAY_END1);
  var session1StaffRecords = GetStaff(scheduleTemplateId, 1);

  return new ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo(..., await session1ProgramRecords.ConfigureAwait(false), ...,
    await session1StaffRecords.ConfigureAwait(false));
}



private async Task<ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo> GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo2(dynamic record, int scheduleTemplateId) {
  var session2Programs = this.GetPrograms(scheduleTemplateId, record.TMPLDAY_START2, record.TMPLDAY_END2);
  var session2Staff = GetStaff(scheduleTemplateId, 2);

  return new ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo(..., await session2Programs.ConfigureAwait(false),
    ...., await session2Staff.ConfigureAwait(false));
}



private async Task<ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo> GetSessionScheduleTemplateSessionInfo3(dynamic record, int scheduleTemplateId) {
  var session3Programs = this.GetPrograms(scheduleTemplateId, record.TMPLDAY_START3, record.TMPLDAY_END3);
  var session3Staff = GetStaff(scheduleTemplateId, 3);

  return new ScheduleTemplateSessionInfo(..., await session3Programs.ConfigureAwait(false),
    ...., await session3Staff.ConfigureAwait(false));
}



private async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> TemplateInfoRecords(Guid id) {
  using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenConnection()) {
    return await db.QueryAsync(
      "SELECT " +
      " ... 50+ records ... " +
      "FROM [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY] " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[RESOURCE] ON [dbo].[RESOURCE].RSC_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].RSC_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[LOCATION] Session1Location ON Session1Location.LOC_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].LOC_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[LOCATION] Session2Location ON Session2Location.LOC_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].LOC_LOC_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[LOCATION] Session3Location ON Session3Location.LOC_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].LOC2_LOC_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[NOTE] Session1Note ON Session1Note.NOTE_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].NOTE_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[NOTE] Session2Note ON Session2Note.NOTE_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].NOT_NOTE_ID " +
      "JOIN [dbo].[NOTE] Session3Note ON Session3Note.NOTE_ID = [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY].NOT2_NOTE_ID " +
      "WHERE [dbo].[RESOURCE].Id = @id ", new { id }).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}



private async Task<IEnumerable<ScheduleDayInfo>> ScheduleDayInfos(Guid scheduleId) {
  using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenConnection()) {
    const string query = "SELECT DISTINCT(SCHDP_DATE) AS Date, [dbo].[RESOURCE].Id FROM [dbo].[SCHEDULE_DPART] " +
                          "JOIN [dbo].[RESOURCE] ON [dbo].[RESOURCE].RSC_ID = [dbo].[SCHEDULE_DPART].RSC_ID " +
                          "WHERE [dbo].[RESOURCE].Id = @id AND SCHEDULE_DPART.SCHDP_TYPE IN ('N', 'S') " +
                          "AND [dbo].[SCHEDULE_DPART].SCHDP_DATE >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())";
    return
      (await db.QueryAsync(query, new { id = scheduleId }).ConfigureAwait(false))
        .Select(record => new ScheduleDayInfo(ScheduleDayGuidProvider.Generate(record.Id, record.Date), record.Date));
  }
}



private async Task<ScheduleTemplateInfoSessionProgram[]> GetPrograms(int templateDayId, int sessionStartTime, int sessionEndTime) {
  using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenConnection()) {
    const string query = "SELECT " +
                          "...13 columns, mostly text, numbers and BIT converts ..." +
                          "FROM [dbo].[TEMPLATE_PROGRAM] " +
                          "JOIN [dbo].[NOTE] ON [NOTE].[NOTE_ID] = [TEMPLATE_PROGRAM].[NOTE_ID] " +
                          "WHERE [TMPLDAY_ID] = @templateDayId AND [TMPLPRG_STARTTIME] >= @sessionStartTime AND [TMPLPRG_ENDTIME] <= @sessionEndTime";

    var parameters = new {
      templateDayId,
      sessionStartTime,
      sessionEndTime
    };
    return
      (await db.QueryAsync(query, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false))
        .Select(record => new ScheduleTemplateInfoSessionProgram((int?)record.Id, ..., (bool)record.PublishSlots, ...).ToArray();
  }
}



private async Task<int[]> GetStaff(int scheduleTemplateIntId, int sequenceNumber) {
  using (var db = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenConnection()) {
    const string query =
      "SELECT [CPS_ID] FROM [dbo].[TEMPLATE_DAY_STAFF] 
          WHERE [TMPLDAY_ID] = @scheduleTemplateIntId AND [TMPLDAY_DAYPART_NR] = @sequenceNumber";

    var parameters = new {
      scheduleTemplateIntId,
      sequenceNumber
    };

    return (await db.QueryAsync<int>(query, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Are we making any obvious/horrible errors in here? I'm fairly sure we're already utilizing the `async` & `await` operaters fairly efficient. I'm starting to think this might be an external thing that's causing the spikes in delays. Unrelated to the coding?

Comment: What's with all the ellipses?

Comment: It means code has been left out there. So ignore those. Apologies, should have specified.

Comment: You actually have _I've occasionally left out some code because not relevant._. Someone (@eurotrash) didn't read the question :-P

Comment: _it 'builds up' gradually and drops down quickly after about half a minute_ - do you have _more_ code where you gather or process the objects from the database? it looks like the garbage collection kicks-in. These here are only queries. I don''t think there is anything we can do about them. Some other parts of you code seem to be inefficient.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yes, I've already suspected garbage collection to have a hand in this. However, as far I know, C# / .NET has automatic garbage collection, correct? How can I investigate this? I'll see if there's any other code relevant.

Comment: When SQL times vary is it often locks.  You can try with (nolock).  That may not be an acceptable production fix but it will identify locks as a problem.

Comment: Mmhmm, I've tried monitoring the SQL earlier. I'm fairly sure I 'collected' it all. Executing the code multiple times was nowhere close to 5 seconds, even though executing there isn't the same as executing through client/server or api. All of the SQL is reading, so I'm not sure if no-lock would be acceptable.

Comment: Could we take a look at the critical parts of `_dbConnectionFactory`? It would be helpful to review what's going on with the underlying class that provides the `OpenConnection()` and `QueryAsync()` methods.

Comment: Do your tables have the proper indexes? Have you looked at the execution plans of the queries you execute?

Comment: @GillesDeVylder I think most modern .Net performance profilers can measure stuff pretty well, including time spent on collecting garbage. You should run your app with profiler attached to pinpoint the problem. If you don't have a profiler, you can grab a trial version of https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: What type of database system is this using? Is it oracle, mysql, sql server?

Comment: SQL Server is the back-end